# as3, flash fl tween transitions freezing

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, tween

I have a bunch of different tweens going on in different movie clips but it seems that sometimes the tweens will freeze halfway through during my transitions.

This guy is having the same problem and his question was answered but I'm not too sure exactly what they meant when they told him what to do: http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=222606

Do I have to import my tween classes at the very beginning of my site in the root then reference those in every movie clip as opposed to importing the classes in each movieclip separately?

Here is an example of a tween inside one of my movieclips:

```
// Import classes
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;

// Bring in elements with tweening
var bandY:Tween = new Tween(band, "y", Strong.easeOut, 533, 259, 3, true);
var boxY:Tween = new Tween(box, "y", None.easeOut, -122, 0, 1, true);
var signY:Tween = new Tween(sign, "y", Regular.easeOut, 551, 224, 1.5, true);
var signX:Tween = new Tween(sign, "x", Regular.easeOut, -17, 82, 1.5, true);
var dragonMaskWidth:Tween = new Tween(dragonMask, "width", Regular.easeOut, 30, 500, 3, true);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What the post meant in the forum you referenced was that they OP should try creating non-local variables for the tweens.  SO, instead of doing this

```
function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    nextPage = e.currentTarget.mcTarget;
    var theTween:Tween = new Tween(currentPage,"alpha",Strong.easeOut,1,0,1,true);
    theTween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, onTween);
}
```

They were saying to try this:

```
var theTween:Tween;  
function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    nextPage = e.currentTarget.mcTarget;
    theTween = new Tween(currentPage,"alpha",Strong.easeOut,1,0,1,true);
    theTween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, onTween);
}
```

By doing this, the scope of the variable "theTween" is not local to the onClick event handler function, but rather it is in the same scope as the function itself.

My biggest recommendation would be to try using a different tweening library, there are TONS out there.  The built-in library for Tweening in flash leaves a lot to be desired IMHO.  I would take a look at one or more of these:

[TweenLite](http://blog.greensock.com/tweenlite/)

[Tweener](http://code.google.com/p/tweener/)

[GTween](http://blog.greensock.com/tweenlite/)

[AS3 Animation System](http://www.boostworthy.com/blog/?p=170)

There are many more... just take a look

Comment: I'll for sure try those out. I'm still fairly new to as3 but I will have to look into these. Thanks.

Comment: Should timers be put outside functions too in the same way?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I figured out what the other guy was saying.
I have to move tween variables outside of functions, makes sense.
It was hard to see the difference in their code at first.
Also realized that this was bad example code to use because there's no functions.